# Is it possible to limit the number of users currently accessing af file?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ftp

I am currently working on a project that involves audio streaming. It is quite essential that I limit the number of people simultaneously accessing the file due to copyright issues, but Google hasn't been my friend in finding a proper solution. My site (which is run on WordPress, thus PHP and mysql) will be running on an ftp server where the soundfile will also be hosted. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

Comment: First you need to store the IP address of current users, then if the number of users excess limit disable or hide the file link, I don't know it's a standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Page Restrict Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/)

Restrict certain pages or posts to logged in users

This plugin will allow you to restrict all, none, or certain pages/posts to logged in users only.

In some cases where you are using WordPress as a CMS and only want logged in users to have access to the content or where you want users to register for purposes unknown so that they can see the content, then this plugin is what you are looking for.

Simple admin interface to select all, none, or some of your pages/posts. This now works for posts!

> You can [Download Plugin](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/pagerestrict.zip) from here and Read [pagerestrict Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/)